# Mapping JSONObject to Rest Template to gain authentication in spring security

Tags: json, spring-boot, thymeleaf, resttemplate

I need to make a POST request to /user/auth with 'username' and 'password' json body to retrieve user auth from spring security endpoint.

I have a thymeleaf login form. it sends 'username' and 'password' to my custom authentication filter endpoint.

The endpoint is being triggered, but the object it receives is null.

I'm able to use postman to send a json body to the endpoint and i can login with success, but when using the thymeleaf form, the object i send is null.

Something I've tried:
using a pre-auth endpoint to intercept the request and processes the thymeleaf object into json.
I think I'm missing the mark on how to use the RestTemplate, though.

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/preauth", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public UserDto preAuth(@ModelAttribute LoginRequestModel loginRequestModel) {
        log.info("username to test: {}", loginRequestModel.getUsername());
        log.info("password to test: {}", loginRequestModel.getPassword());
// ^^ these are coming back correct ^^


        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("username", loginRequestModel.getUsername());
        jsonObject.put("password", loginRequestModel.getPassword());

jsonObject.toMap().forEach((s, o) -> System.out.println(s + " : " + o));

// ^^ this also comes back correct ^^
// dont understand how to get this JSONObject inserted into the Rest Template

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(jsonObject);

        restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/user/auth", loginRequestModel, LoginRequestModel.class);

        return userInfo;

    }
```

```
<form action="#" method="POST" th:action="@{/user/auth/preauth}" th:object="${loginRequestModel}">
    <p>Username: <input th:field="*{username}" type="text"/></p>
    <p>Password: <input th:field="*{password}" type="text"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" value="Reset"/></p>
```

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
@Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        log.info("attempting to authenticate user");
        try {
            log.info("trying to map object");
            LoginRequestModel creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginRequestModel.class);


            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getUsername(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>()
                    )
            );

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
```

for whatever reason, the request.getInputStream() is returning as null when i try to call it directly from thymeleaf form in the browser.

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - /user/auth?username=admin&password=admin at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AuthenticationFilter' 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/user/auth'; against '/user/auth' 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG t.j.w.j.a.s.AuthenticationFilter - Request is to process authentication 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO  t.j.w.j.a.s.AuthenticationFilter - attempting to authenticate user 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO  t.j.w.j.a.s.AuthenticationFilter - trying to map object 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO  t.j.w.j.a.s.AuthenticationFilter - the exception was caught! 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO  t.j.w.j.a.s.AuthenticationFilter - the headers:: 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO  t.j.w.j.a.s.AuthenticationFilter - null 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO  t.j.w.j.a.s.AuthenticationFilter - null 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.w.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@46b257b6 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 1, column: 0]
    at tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.app.security.AuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(AuthenticationFilter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4146)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4001)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3071)
    at tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.app.security.AuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(AuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you tried  using`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` at your `AutenticationFilter` ?

Comment: My AuthenticationFilter Extends it, so yes.

Comment: Check my answer, is that what you looking for.

Comment: [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  t.j.w.j.a.s.AuthenticationFilter - attempting to authenticate user 
[http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  t.j.w.j.a.s.AuthenticationFilter - trying to map object 
[http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  t.j.w.j.a.s.AuthenticationFilter - null 
[http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  t.j.w.j.a.s.AuthenticationFilter - null 
[http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.w.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@76dc8972

Comment: i added the full logs for when i try to make a GET request directly with the thymeleaf form. it is exactly the same when i try to send a rest template.

Comment: `GET` ? you should make POST

Comment: yeah, you're right, sorry I was confused when writing the post, i am actually making a post to user/auth. i meant that i tried making another method that accepts GET to intercept.

Comment: In your controller you are using `RestTemplate` why is that ? isn't your project SpringMVC and uses Spring Secuirty /?

Comment: when i try to send a post to the endpoint from my thymeleaf template, the request that is received by the spring security endpoint is null. i'm trying to find a way to send the jsonobject internally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get the `userName` and `password` as below when you are using `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`

```
 @Override
 public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(sessionTimeout);

    CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = getAuthRequest(request);
    _log.info("");
    setDetails(request, authRequest);

    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
}

    private CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
         String username = obtainUsername(request);
     String password = obtainPassword(request);
    _log.info("UserName IN Filter : "+username);
    _log.info("UserName IN Filter : "+password);

    return new CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help me, i'm able to log in by sending a json body using postman, but the request isnt returning any data when i try to call it using the thymeleaf form. and I dont understand how to send json internally, I was trying to use a RestTemplate but I'm not sure how to get it to send the json.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! just had to send the thymeleaf object to the preauth endpoint and use HttpServletRequest to request.login() with the username and password directly from the html. no mapping to json required.

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/preauth", produces = "application/json")
    public String preAuth(@ModelAttribute LoginRequestModel loginRequestModel, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, ServletException {

        request.login(loginRequestModel.getUsername(),loginRequestModel.getPassword());

        return "index";

    }
```